# Block code formatting in Coda 2

Tags: coda

Despite the bad reviews, I've decided to splurge on Coda 2.  There is a feature I can't seem to find though - code formatting on existing code.

In Sublimetext 2 you can highlight a block of code, and with a few key strokes, have it automatically format / indent.  I don't see this in Coda 2.  Does it exist?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may need to use a plugin to accomplish it:

http://www.chipwreck.de/blog/software/coda-php/

Comment: Thanks.  Was hoping it did it natively- I'm kind of confused as to why it doesn't.